# Darlingtons, MOSFETS, and bipolar junctions

Tags: transistors, component-selection

I realize there are [dozens upon dozens of kinds of transistors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Transistor_types), each used for specific purposes. Sometimes there is great overlap; multiple kinds may work in a given circuit, but at times only a specific transistor is ideal.

Without reading all of the specifics of each kind, is there some kind of quick reference or guide that is useful when researching the type of transistor to use? For example, I'm familiar with some kinds of transistor, and often use them in my projects. Eventually someone will review the project and say "Why don't you use X instead of Y there?" It's at that point that I research X and learn something new.

If there was a "handy infographic of transistors" it might have helped me research all the types related to "X" so I'd have known to read up on them.

*(For example, I was attempting to use a Zener diode in a circuit but wasn't aware that what I really wanted was a transient voltage suppressor. Something showing how Zeners and TVS's are related might have been useful.)*

Searching the internet doesn't yield much other than a few transistor family trees and the like:

[image: Transistor Types]

*from [Learning About Electronics](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Transistor-types-hierarchy)*

Does anyone know of (or wish to create!) a useful transistor selection guide that doesn't assume you are familiar with all the species of transistor?

Comment: [IGBTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulated-gate_bipolar_transistor) too

Comment: There are also Japanese and European transistors in addition to the normal ones.

Comment: I think that diagram is brain-damaged. For starters, CMOS isn't a kind of transistors, but rather an arrangement of distinct N-channel and P-channel MOSFETS. There are also transistors that don't fit in this hierarchy, like IGBTs.

Comment: @Phil I sort of wanted a "brain-damaged" chart to illustrate the need for a better one. I think there exists a great opportunity for a clear transistor infographic.

Comment: I don't think this question is a good fit for SE because it is too open-ended. There's no one factual answer. I once wrote a long rant on Wikipedia about why it's not really possible to make a hierarchy like what's suggested in your example diagram: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Root_page/archive3#Root.2Fbranch_is_a_bad_idea. A lot of that is specific to WP, but the section "Creates hierarchy even if you don't want it" applies here.

Comment: It's been debated for years on StackOverflow, whether questions are a good fit if they don't have a "single" answer. While I agree that it's not a perfect fit, if people can provide useful transistor reference guides, the votes for such answers provide insight as to which are "better" than others.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your question distills to "how should I use transistors?" and the [answer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0962852570)
[fills](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750644273) [whole](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0849380804) [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0748740759). Distributors carry [tens of thousands of different transistors](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=us&KeyWords=transistor) to meet the needs of designers. As a consequence, I don't believe you can create an infographic that is complete, correct, and useful at the same time.

What I *can* give you is a set of heuristics:

**Choose...**

- **...a [BJT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor) when**:

  - you need a current amplifier¹
  - you have power to burn, so the required base current doesn't bother you
  - the "bottom leg" of the transistor can get pulled above the "top leg," and you need this path to not conduct when that happens, as it would in a MOSFET due to the [body diode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_MOSFET#Body_diode)
  - you need to exploit the [C-B or E-B diode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#Theory_and_modeling)²
- **...a [JFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFET) when**:

  - you only need small-signal amplification³
  - the base current of a BJT would be a problem in your application⁴
  - you need a voltage-controlled resistance
  - you need higher [transconductance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transconductance) or lower [flicker noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_noise) than you'd get with a MOSFET
  - you need a [small, discrete, low-component-count constant current source](http://www.vishay.com/docs/70596/70596.pdf)
- **...a [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosfet) when**:

  - you need a switch⁵
  - you need higher input impedance than a BJT, and can't find an IGBT that fits the bill
  - you can't find a JFET studly enough to control the power your circuit needs⁶
  - you were looking at JFETs, but then realized you needed [enhancement mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhancement_mode) operation⁷
  - you want to exploit the inherent body diode as a feature, rather than consider it a problem to cope with⁸
- **...an [IGBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGBT) when**:

  - you need something that behaves like a high input impedance BJT

I've largely ignored transistor combinations above, because once you start combining transistors, the possibilities literally become infinite. Today you have a range from [Darlington pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor) to billion-transistor [ICs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit), with new circuit arrangements being designed all the time.

There are many, many more types of transistors, but for the most part, you want to figure out all the above before moving on to them. The others are usually derivatives of the above classes, so without the initial grounding, you will have no basis to select one of the exotics. Examples:

- Need to exploit the fact that a BJT's base is light-sensitive when not encapsulated? Okay, that's a [phototransistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototransistor#Other_modes_of_operation).
- Need [multiple emitters or collectors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/105777/2523) on your BJT? Sure, no problem, that’s easy to create in silicon; it’s often useful and therefore often seen at the custom silicon level.
- Need a BJT, but a whole lot faster? Okay, we just won't use doped silicon for everything, we'll combine materials into a [heterojunction transistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterojunction_bipolar_transistor).
- Need to pack transistors in even tighter than normal, but running into trouble with the [short channel effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-channel_effect)? Okay, we'll give you a [FinFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finfet).
- Need something that works kinda like a diode, and kinda like a BJT? Okay, we'll blur the lines for you and give you a [UJT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unijunction_transistor).
- Need something like an IGBT but with lower loss and higher current gain? A [SiC junction transistor](http://www.genesicsemi.com/commercial-sic/sic-junction-transistors/) might be what you're looking for.

---

**Footnotes**

1. You can also make voltage amplifiers with bipolars, of course.
2. Small-signal BJTs make great low-leakage diodes.
3. JFET-like power devices exist, such as  [Infineon's CoolSIC](http://infineon.com/coolsic), but they're relatively new and exotic, thus expensive.
4. This is why there are so many JFET-input op-amps.
5. All the other transistor types can act as a switch, too, but MOSFETs excel at this.
6. A power MOSFET isn't quite the same thing as a power JFET,³ and it isn't the only alternative, but it is often the simplest, cheapest alternative.
7. JFETs are inherently depletion-mode devices, only.
8. [One my answers here at EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12038/increasing-voltage/12069#12069) shows such a circuit.

Comment: You tackled this correctly. The naivety of the question needed to be addressed. An infographic could still be useful, but would obviously need to be incomplete. Perhaps only the *n* most common transistor families would be represented. I find it difficult to absorb all the information about transistors because there are *so many types* as you pointed out. It's difficult to find a starting point... Which, I suppose, is what I'm asking for.